# Send HTTP query with verb different from GET / POST in Codename one?

Tags: http, codenameone, http-verbs

Is it possible to send HTTP queries with verbs other than GET and POST in Codename one? Like PUT and DELETE. From what I see in the documentation, it is not possible: [link](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html)

But I think that PUT and DELETE are so often used for REST APIs for update and delete that there should be a way to send HTTP PUT. 
So is it possible and if yes, could you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call PUT and/or DELETE by doing:

```
        ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest();
        ...
        req.setHttpMethod("PUT");
```

or

```
        req.setHttpMethod("DELETE");
```